# How do I implement this completion handler shown in Apple's Core Data documentation?

Tags: swift, core-data, closures

I'm trying to implement Core Data in my app, as described by Apple's ["Core Data Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1).

So far I feel I understand the stack and how it's implemented. However there's one line of code that has me scratching my head. ["Initializing the Core Data Stack"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1) provides the following example code for initialization:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    init(completionClosure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores() { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
            }
            completionClosure()
        }
    }
}
```

How does this code imply I initialize the Core Data stack?

Right now, I initialize a DataController object in my initial view controller like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let dataController: DataController = DataController(completionClosure: /* buildtime error for the things I've tried here */)
}
```

However, as you can see, I'm not sure what's supposed to be passed in for the completion closure. Xcode gives me a buildtime error whenever I try to pass in an empty closure, which is what I assume should be passed in since I don't see anything left for DataController to perform in its initialization.

My guess is that the completion closure is supposed to perform some asynchronous process. But I'm at a loss as to what that is. Any ideas?

**Edit:** A commenter pointed out that the DataController class declaration won't compile. I forgot that I had made some adjustments to clear the errors:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    init(completionClosure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        self.managedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores() { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
            }
            completionClosure()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure how to initialize Core Data this way though.

Comment: Where do you initialize the managedObjectContext? Some part of code must be missing here, since this certainly doesn't compile.

Comment: That's a good point, I don't know. The code above was copy pasted from the "Initializing the Core Data Stack" link. I had to change it a bit to clear the errors from Xcode. I'll add my edited code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the simplest way (and the way I did it a couple of times in the past) is to create a temporary project with CoreData enabled and copy over everything that is needed.

Just a few steps:

- From `AppDelegate.swift`, copy everything from `applicationWillTerminate()` to the end of the file over to your `AppDelegate.swift`.
- Add `import CoreData` to the beginning of your `AppDelegate`.
- Then you can delete that temporary project.
- Create the Data Model (⌘N and choose "Data Model" under "CoreData" section). Let's say you call it `myDataModel.xcdatamodeld`.
- Modify this line in `AppDelegate.swift`: `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "myDataModel")`

And you're ready to go!